# Angular 9 - NGRX How to register a "global" reducer

Tags: angular, ngrx

Let's say I have a state `AnimalState` that looks like this:

```
{
  cats: Cat[];
  dogs: Dog[];
}
```

Here how the reducers are defined :

```
export const catsReducer = createReducer([],
  on(AnimalAction.loadCats,
    (state, { cats }) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        cats
      };
    }),
);

export const dogsReducer = createReducer([],
  on(AnimalAction.loadDogs,
    (_, { dogs }) => {
      return dogs;
    }),
);

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AnimalState> = {
  cats: catsReducer,
  dogs: dogsReducer,
};
```

I then inject reducers into my custom module with an InjectionToken such as :

```
const reducerToken = new InjectionToken<ActionReducerMap<AnimalState>>(
'ANIMAL_REDUCERS', 
{ factory: () => reducers });
StoreModule.forFeature("animal", reducerToken),
```

My question is how can I create and register a reducer that will use both `cats` and `dogs` values.

Answer (score 0):

Well you would want to split the reducer and initial states:

```
const initialCatState: Cat[] = []


export const catsReducer = createReducer(initialCatState,
  on(CatAction.update,
    (state, { cats }) => {
      return cats;
    }),
);


const initialDogState: Dog[] = []


export const dogsReducer = createReducer(initialDogState,
  on(DogAction.update,
    ((state: Dog[]), { dogs }) => {
      return dogs;
    }),
  on(DogAction.add,
    ((state: Dog[]), { dog }) => {
      return [...dogs, dog];
    }),
);
```

And then register two features:

```
StoreModule.forFeature("cats", catsReducer),
StoreModule.forFeature("dogs", dogsReducer),
```

and to select

```
export const selectCats = createFeatureSelector('cats');
export const selectDogs = createFeatureSelector('dogs');
```

Comment: I would have the same issue in one reducer I would not be able to access state.cats & state.dogs if i'm not mistaken ?

Comment: Well there is only really one store at the end of the day, the rest is typing.

The above will create one store with two objects, `state.dogs` and `state.cats`, the selectors should always point at the root of your store.

Comment: selectors should be something like this: `const selectCats = createFeatureSelector('cats')` instead of selecting in reducer as you are doing. reducers should always return the state and update properties synchronously.

Comment: In reducer you want to react to `addCats` or `updateCats`. then you want to `return { ...state, cats: action.cats }` and pass the new data in an action

Comment: On top of that you want to keep them as flat as possible, so avoid having `Animals => Cats, Dogs`, instead register `Cats` and `Dogs` at root level if possible

Comment: But how in reducers to react to updateCats such as : 

(state, { cats }) => ({...state, cats, dogs: [] })

Comment: Thanks though sorry, but I am not sure to completly understand. What's the difference in your example and in mine that allow to have the full state instead of the cats state in the reducer

Comment: In your case you are using `ActionReducerMap` to create one `Animals`-feature with two children. In my case we are not using `ActionReducerMap` and instead Selectors while we register two seperate features directly at root level